# Apply/Lambda with if clause and diff()

Tags: python, lambda, apply, diff

The problem to solve is to do computations between rows and within rows for series data and to filter on the value in one column matching the previous row value.

This is my data:
[Columns of cummulative data by date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI0jo.png)

date.        cumulativePositiveTests.cumulativeNegativeTests stateName
7  2020-03-15   1.0                     143.0                   Alaska
8  2020-03-16.  1.0                     143.0                   Alaska
9. 2020-03-17   3.0                     334.0                   Alaska
10 2020-03-18   6.0                     406.0                   Alaska
11 2020-03-19   6.0                     432.0                   Alaska

When I was only dealing with one state this worked:

```
COVID_df['Dly_PosTests'] = COVID_df['cumulativePositiveTests'].diff()
COVID_df['Dly_NegTests'] = COVID_df['cumulativeNegativeTests'].diff()
COVID_df['Dly_Tests'] = COVID_df['Dly_PosTests'] + COVID_df['Dly_NegTests']
COVID_df['Dly_Pos_Rate'] = (100* (COVID_df['Dly_PosTests'] / COVID_df['Dly_Tests']))
```

Now that I have more than one state I was thinking about an apply/lambda with a diff(), but I cannot get the syntax correct.

Tried this:

```
for i in range(7,(len(Chart_Data)-1):
    Chart_Data.apply(lambda x:(x['cumulativePositiveTests'].diff()),axis=1) 
    if Chart_Data['stateName'].shift() == Chart_Data['stateName'] else None)
```

Thanks,

Alison

Answer (score 0):

Think I got it, but wondering if something else would perform better?

```
def CovidCalc(gr):
     Chart_Data['Dly_PosTests'] = Chart_Data['cumulativePositiveTests'].diff()
     Chart_Data['Dly_NegTests'] = Chart_Data['cumulativeNegativeTests'].diff()
     Chart_Data['Dly_Tests'] = Chart_Data['Dly_PosTests'] + Chart_Data['Dly_NegTests']
     Chart_Data['Dly_Pos_Rate'] = (100* (Chart_Data['Dly_PosTests'] / Chart_Data['Dly_Tests']))
     return None
```

*then*

```
covid_range=(len(Chart_Data)-1)
```

then

```
for i in range(7,covid_range):
           Chart_Data.groupby("stateName").apply(CovidCalc)
```

Thanks to this article: [How to use the Split-Apply-Combine strategy in Pandas groupby](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-the-split-apply-combine-strategy-in-pandas-groupby-29e0eb44b62e)